# Insert values from table consisting of one column into one row in another one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to "transpose" a table in SQL Server with one column and 4 rows:

```
Col0 
-----
Val1
Val2
Val3
Val4
```

into a table variable `@t table(col1, col2, col3, col4)` with one row and 4 columns:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
-----+------+------+-----
Val1 | Val2 | Val3 | Val4
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

I am a beginner when it comes to SQL Server, thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

No really simply way, but you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then col0 end),
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then col0 end),
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then col0 end),
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then col0 end)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

If the table only has 4 rows and 1 column it seems like it would be easiest to just re-type the values.  To do it referencing the table it could be something like this

```
select max(case when col0='Val1' then col0 end) col1,
       max(case when col0='Val2' then col0 end) col2,
       max(case when col0='Val3' then col0 end) col3,
       max(case when col0='Val4' then col0 end) col4
from tTable;
```